# Oracle Apex installation - SGA/PGA configuration requirement

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

When preparing to install Oracle APEX on a db instance version 19c, I came accross the following instruction on document https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmig/apex-installation-requirements.html

> Oracle Application Express requires the system global area (SGA) and
> program global area (PGA) to be at least 300 MB.

I checked parameter and found the following value

```
SQL> SHOW PARAMETER MEMORY_TARGET

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
memory_target                        big integer 0
```

on step 4, the documentation states

> If the value is 0, your database is using manual memory management.
> Consult the Oracle Database Administrator’s Guide to learn how to
> configure an equivalent memory size using manual memory management,
> instead of continuing with the steps that follow.

I consulted Oracle Database Administrator's Guide, but I did not understand how to check that requirement when value of memory_target is 0.

How to determine if database instance configuration is in accordance with this requirement if memory_target is set to 0?

current instance configuration

```
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 1536M
pga_aggregate_limit                  big integer 3G
sga_target                           big integer 6G
sga_max_size                         big integer 6G
```

Comment: What are the values of the `pga_aggregate_target`, `pga_aggregate_limit`, `sga_target`, and `sga_max_size` parameters?

Comment: @pmdba, I updated the description/body of the question adding the values of these parameters

Comment: So your SGA is set for 6G and your PGA for 1.5G. I think you've more than met the 300M requirement (which is actually very, very small).